# Pandas match values and create new table without duplicates

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following 2 data frames:

```
sentences = pd.read_csv(
    'sentences and translations/SpaSentandEng2.csv', sep='\t')
print(sentences.head())

words = pd.read_csv(
    'sentences and translations/5kWords.csv', sep='\t', header=None)
print(words.head())
```

That output the following:

```
0                   Tengo que irme a dormir                   I have to go to sleep.
1               Simplemente no sé qué decir           I just don't know what to say.
2                 Yo estaba en las montañas                  I was in the mountains.
3                     No sé si tengo tiempo         I don't know if I have the time.
4  La educación en este mundo me decepciona  Education in this world disappoints me.
     0      1
0   de  17177
1   no  15397
2    a  14887
3   la  14653
4  que  14446
```

The words data frame represents the frequencies of each word in the "Spa" column of the sentences data frame.

I am trying to create a new data frame by matching each word with a sentence and its translation such as:

```
   spa                    eng                                 word
1  estoy de acuerdo       I agree                               de
2  no sé si tengo tiempo  I don't know if I have the time       sé
.
.
.
```

The sentence should not contain the word at the start or end and I want to avoid matching a word with a sentence if that sentence has already been matched with another word.

I can match the word with a sentence with the following:

```
sentences[sentences['Spa'].str.contains(" " +
                                               words[0][0]+' ', regex=False, case=False, na=False)]
```

But, I do not know what to do from here. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A different approach

1. basically around join between words and sentences using `explode()`
2. when split is done use slices to exclude first and last word
3. keep a list of used sentences so they can be excluded
4. where join will give multiple records use `iloc` slice to take first one only

```
import re
trans = '''0                   Tengo que irme a dormir                   I have to go to sleep.
1               Simplemente no sé qué decir           I just don't know what to say.
2                 Yo estaba en las montañas                  I was in the mountains.
3                     No sé si tengo tiempo         I don't know if I have the time.
4  La educación en este mundo me decepciona  Education in this world disappoints me.'''
wordst = '''0   de  17177
1   no  15397
2    a  14887
3   la  14653
4  en  14446'''
sentances = pd.DataFrame([[col.strip() for col in re.split("  ",t) if col!=""] for t in trans.split("\n")], 
             columns=["ID","spa","eng"]).drop("ID",1)
words = pd.DataFrame([[col.strip() for col in re.split("  ",t) if col!=""] for t in wordst.split("\n")], 
             columns=["ID","word", "count"]).drop("ID",1)


sjoin=sentances.assign(word=sentances.apply(lambda r: r["spa"].split(" ")[1:-1], axis=1))\
    .explode("word") # strip off first and last words

used=[]
df = pd.DataFrame()
for word in words["word"].values:
    df = pd.concat([df, 
                    words[words["word"]==word]  # match current word
                    .merge(sjoin[~sjoin["spa"].isin(used)]).  # exclude previously matched sentances
                    drop("count", 1).reindex(columns=["spa","eng","word"]).iloc[0:1,]]) # cleanup,  but most importantly just take first sentance for this word
    used = df["spa"].values
df
```

**output**

```
                        spa                             eng word
 Simplemente no sé qué decir  I just don't know what to say.   no
     Tengo que irme a dormir          I have to go to sleep.    a
   Yo estaba en las montañas         I was in the mountains.   en
```